# No aparece opción para Castear en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Soy nueva en Android Studio y mi problema es que antes siempre me aparecía subrayado en rojo lo que quería castear y los podía hacer con clic derecho. Pero ahora no puedo hacer eso y no se porqué.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no entiendo tu problema, en el código que estás mostrando, se castea exitosamente. ¿tienes algún ejemplo en el que **no se castee exitosamente?**

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: No estoy seguro si le entiendo: consulte la [documentación de atajos de teclado de Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html); intente además cerrar y abrir nuevamente el IDE Android Studio "es posible que usted haya deshabilitado sin intención el Intellisense".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probablemente porque actualizaste Android Studio. Si vas a la documentacion de [`findViewById`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)) nos dice en la nota:

> Nota: En la mayoria de los casos, dependiendo del soporte del
>   compilador, se emite al resultado automaticamente como el tipo de la clase de destino. Si el tipo no es restringido, puede que requiere una conversion explicita

Osea, el compilador lo hace por ti.

Puedes deshabilitarlo dando `alt+enter`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y habilitarlo otra vez en la `Archivo->Configuracion`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque deshabilitando no logre que me marcara error por la conversión implícita.

Answer (score -1):

Si no realiza el autocomplete, asegura no tengas habilitada la opción **Power Save Mode**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si esta activada, esto puede ser la causa de no activar esta característica.